# I have a question about the gas charge

Tags: go-ethereum

I have a question about the gas charge. I want the user to pay.

How do I get it. There are certain wallet addresses. They'll send 0 ether.

the tokens they earn will be uploaded to their accounts.

what is the code of it.

I'm sorry about my little English.

Answer (score 1):

The fees of a transaction are credited to the block miner by protocol, from a transaction you cannot change the fees recipient.

But there are alternatives, for example an ERC20 token can implement a fee that is a percentage of the amount of every transfer.